# NullPointerException: null playframework 2.1.1 file upload

Tags: java, playframework-2.1

i am just new-ish in play framework, I was Trying to code upload file with playframework 2.1.1, but I am getting this exception [NullPointerException]: null
I have following code in My Controller and using [this link](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaFileUpload)

```
package controllers;

//import com.ning.http.client.FilePart;
import play.mvc.Http.MultipartFormData;
import play.mvc.Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart;
import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import play.data.*;
import static play.data.Form.*;
import java.io.File;
import models.*;
import views.html.*;

public class Application extends Controller {
  
    public static Result index() {
        return ok(index.render("My App"));
    }
public static Result upload(){
    MultipartFormData body=request().body().asMultipartFormData();
    MultipartFormData.FilePart picture=body.getFile("picture");//Error is here 
 
    if(picture!=null){
        //String fileName=picture.getFileName(); and if I uncomment this line it also show an error for 'value not find 'getFileName' ' is there any import is needed?
        String contentType=picture.getContentType();
        File file=picture.getFile();
        return ok("File Uploaded");
    }
    else 
    {
        flash("error", "Missing File");
        return redirect(routes.Application.index());
    }
//File file = request().body().asRaw().asFile();
//return ok("File uploaded");

}  

}
```

and following code in View that is app/views/upload.scala.html

```
@helper.form(action = routes.Application.upload, 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data") {
    
    <input type="file" name="picture">
    
    <p>
        <input type="submit">
    </p>
    
}
```

please give some suggestion that where i am wrong.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could you please share the stacktrace?

Comment: Did you follow the instruction in the link that the HTTP method should be `POST` and not `GET`? If you used `GET` then the HTTP body will be empty...

Comment: @Asifsid88  There is no Stack Trace just this error NullPointerException at this line "    MultipartFormData.FilePart picture=body.getFile("picture"); " and maba I have this thing in My routes file POST     /upload                         controllers.Application.upload() but still I am stuck in This null Value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't post the `routes` file, but by the error I guess that you are mapping the request to a `GET`instead of `POST`.

The reasoning is that you get a `NullPointerException` when calling a method in `body`. `body`is initialized in the previous line from the `request` object, retrieving the contents as `multipartFormData`.

Your form snippet properly declares the form as `multipart/form-data` and maps to the controller's method as expected. This means that the only reason why you shouldn't get the contents is that the request has an empty body, and in this scenario that would only be in a `GET`request.

Of course, there may be a more exotic reason, but I bet that's the one.

Comment: I also have the same problem. I am submitting the form through `AJAX`, my `routes` file has `POST` method and in `ajax` call also, I'm passing the `POST` method. I have specified the `enctype` as `multipart/form-data` in form tag. But I'm getting `null` when I `access request().body().asMultipartFormData()`  and I get all data when I access `request().body().asFormUrlEncoded()`.

Comment: Its Solved for my Case now,